# Add custom text to menu

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

How i can add custom text to menu?
I want such structure in output:

```
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>services
        <ul>
             <p>services</p>
             <li><a href="#">service1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">service2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">service3</a>
                 <ul>
                     <p>service3<p>
                     <li><a href="#">service 3.1</a></li>
                 <ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I want to place thise structure in sidebar menu on site with wordpress cms.

Comment: I suggest, that i need to use custom walker, but i can't understand, which way i shoul use it.

Comment: Start by reviewing the code here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide it should help guide you down the right path.

Comment: Found these solution on [stack owerflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251897/how-can-i-add-parent-menu-description-to-my-wordpress-menu). Thanks to all! Question solved.

Answer (score 2):

There is another alt way to do this with CSS3. You would add a link to the WP Menu as normal but make the Location either `javascript:void(0);` or `#` so it doesn't go anywhere (I would say the `javascript...` is the better way to prevent anchor link from firing).

Then in your style.css or CSS doc you can get target those links via the `href` like

```
header .nav li a[href="#"], header .nav li a[href="#"]:hover,
header .nav li a[href="javascript:void(0);"],
header .nav li a[href="javascript:void(0);"]:hover {
    text-decoration:none !important;
    cursor: text !important
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

*Your selectors may be different*

Answer (score -1):

You can add it by back end appearance > menu and create menu and > sub menu by dragging page or posts to your menu and call it where you want to call.

For More Detail See this link [How to Add More Navigation Menus to your WordPress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/?utm_expid=3606929-101.yRvM9BqCTnWwtfcczEfOmg.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F)

OR
You can use the fallowing code for adding specific element to the menu

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><p>Show whatever</p><li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know how to add menus :) I don't know how to add <p> with parrent element name to menu before submenu.

Comment: Thanks, but I need, that <p> was first element in sublist and it should contain name of parent element like in structure in my question.

Answer (score -2):

For this, you have to add a walker class to your WordPress menu,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

and all the walker class inside your wp_nav_menu function

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu'    => 2, //menu id
        'walker'  => new Walker_Quickstart_Menu() //use our custom walker
    ));
    ?>
```

Comment: This is way too vague. Please add the walker code to your answer.